# JSON Array values to use in JQuery and execute function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I’m reading X,Y Coordinates from MySQL Database.

2 files, pretend  the connection is there : coordinate_array, and map.php

**Update here** In coordinate_array:  I am making a multidimensional arrays so I can  then use json_encode($desk). I only need x,y values for the Javascript part.

```
 <?php
      include 'db_conn.php';

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$select_coordinate_query = "SELECT x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$select_coordinate_query);

//see if query is good
if($result === false) {
    die(mysqli_error()); 
}

//array that will have number of desks in map area
       $desk = array();  // just added
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){  

    //get desk array count
    $desk[] = array( array("x" => $row['x_coord']),
           array("y" => $row['y_coord']) 
        );
} //end while loop
      echo json_encode($desk);  //encode array
```

?>

**The code above gives me this :**

[[{"x":"20"},{"y":"20"}],[{"x":"30"},{"y":"30"}],[{"x":"40"},{"y":"40"}],[{"x":"50"},{"y":"50"}]]

In map.php : I am trying to get those value with the use of JQuery. I want to get the values and run a loop that will execute my Paint function which will keep drawing rectangles for every row thats in the table. I am very new with JSON and JQuery and starting to use it.

```
    <canvas id="imageView" width="600" height="500"></canvas>           
    <script type="text/javascript">
```

**NEED HELP HERE PLEASE**

```
                //I have no idea how to get the encoded values
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('coordinate_array.php', function(data)){
    $.each(data, function(k,v){
     Paint(v[0].x, v[1].y);
    });//end each
    });//end get json
     });//end rdy func
```

**I WANT TO EXECUTE THIS FUNCTION**

```
        //function to paint rectangles
        function Paint(x,y)
                {
                var ctx, cv;
                cv = document.getElementById('imageView');
                ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
                ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
                //x-axis,y-axis,x-width,y-width
                ctx.strokeRect(x, y, x+100 , y+100); 
                }
            </script>
```

Thank you in advance it’s much appreciated!

Comment: In your `getJson` call add this line `console.log(data);` and post the output.

Comment: In your Javascript console(F12 in Chrome)...there you should be able to see the output...

Comment: @RobertRozas still nothing.. really weird it wont execute my jquery

Comment: Now first...`$desk` should be defined outside of your while like: `$desk = array();`...inside your while should be: `$desk[] = array( "x"=>$row['x_coord'],"y"=>$Row['y_coord']);`...and outside of the while...at the end of you php script `echo json_encode($desk);` ...not inside the while...

Comment: @RobertRozas ok your method gives me this result: [[{"x":"20"},{"y":"20"}],[{"x":"30"},{"y":"30"}],[{"x":"40"},{"y":"40"}],[{"x":"50"},{"y":"50"}]] WHERE AS in the comments from the answer bellow from Marc B it gives me this instead: [{"coordinate_id":"1","x_coord":"20","y_coord":"20"},{"coordinate_id":"2","x_coord":"30","y_coord":"30"},{"coordinate_id":"3","x_coord":"40","y_coord":"40"},{"coordinate_id":"4","x_coord":"50","y_coord":"50"}]  which one is  the one im suposd to use? one has an extra square bracket compared to the other one....

Comment: You should use the one that fits your needs...which is the best way to you...can you post an example about how it needs to be...

Comment: I used your version. You can see it above in my code. Now my main problem is getting those values with JQuery and using the coordinates to execute my paint function

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/use4bybp/1/

Comment: thanks! it halved work with only JS (it would display half rectangles) now I''m trying to suit my code but I'm getting no luck as I'm trying to change it each time.

Comment: See the commented section: http://jsfiddle.net/5n3zk22u/1/

Comment: Ok i updated all of my code and even posted what the result of my array is. Still no output of the rectangles is shown.. this is really weird. do you think that the values are not being read properly form JQuery?

Comment: Do you have TeamViewer?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the json wrong. it should be encoded AFTER your DB fetch loop completes. Since you're doing the encoding inside the loop, you're spitting out multiple independent JSON-encoded strings, which will be treated as a syntax error on the receiving end.

e.g.

```
while($something) {
   echo json_encode($some_array);
}
```

will spit out

```
[something][something][something]
```

three separate json-encoded arrays jammed up against each other. What you want is something more like this:

```
while($something) {
   build_array();
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

which would spit out

```
[something,something,soemthing]
```

instead.

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and I ended up from this : [{"x":"20"},{"y":"20"}][{"x":"30"},{"y":"30"}][{"x":"40"},{"y":"40"}][{"x":"50"},{"y":"50"}]  TO THIS .. only the last coords from the table : [{"x":"50"},{"y":"50"}] ..

Comment: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch) { $arr[] = $row; } echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: thanks the array worked. How would I ignore the coordinate_id since I only want X,Y from being used into JQuery?

Comment: you're doing `select *` in the query. select only the fields you really want.

Comment: cool, changed it to SELECT x_coord, y_coord FROM coordinates; still wont display the rectangles

Comment: well, your JS code is using `.x` and `.y`, and you're sending over `coord_x` and `coord_y`. so, `select coord_x as x, coord_y as y`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
header('Content-Type: application/json');
in coordinate_array.php

Comment: I did, what will this help with?

Comment: You will get proper headers.